# Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable

Tags: sharepoint

Trying to pull some data from Sharepoint web Services using pagination but I can't get it to return the list of data. I keep getting 'Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumberable' on the return statement.

```
    public List<UserInformationListItem> getAllUsers()
    {
        var userContextList = new List<UserInformationListItem>();
        SharepointDataContext context = new SharepointDataContext(new Uri("http://spserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/"));
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");

        DataServiceQueryContinuation<UserInformationListItem> token = null;
        var response = context.UserInformationList.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<UserInformationListItem>;

        do
        {
            if(token != null)
            {
                response = context.Execute<UserInformationListItem>(token);
                userContextList.AddRange(response);
            }
            else userContextList.AddRange(response);
        }
        while ((token = response.GetContinuation()) != null);

        return response.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I should note that the do-while loop runs about 7 times and the response list gets populated successfully with about 6500 items.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious mistake, just been staring at the screen too long. Should have been returning the userContextList instead...

```
public List<UserInformationListItem> getAllUsers()
{
    var userContextList = new List<UserInformationListItem>();
    SharepointDataContext context = new SharepointDataContext(new Uri("http://spserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/"));
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");

    DataServiceQueryContinuation<UserInformationListItem> token = null;
    var response = context.UserInformationList.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<UserInformationListItem>;

    do
    {
        if(token != null)
        {
            response = context.Execute<UserInformationListItem>(token);
            userContextList.AddRange(response);
        }
        else userContextList.AddRange(response);
    }
    while ((token = response.GetContinuation()) != null);

    return userContextList.ToList();
}
```